# nlminb() does not recognize input data when embebed in foreach()

Tags: r, optimization, resampling, parallel-foreach

I want to conduct a montecarlo resampling scheme using the multicore facility provided by the foreach package combined with package doMC, using a LINUX machine. On each iteration, a self-made function resamples with replacement data contained in data.frame `X`. As a result, I get a new data.frame `X.i` containing the pseudo-sample, which is used as input data into an optimization process using `nlminb()` (target function= `F_1`).  I got no problem by using the standard `for()` command:

```
B=10 # number of iterations in the for(), foreach() loops
ll<-numeric(B) # vector containing the objective value from nlminb() at iteration i.

for (i in 1:B){
               X.i<-f_bwhv(X,resampling=T)
               ll[i]<-nlminb(par,F_1,X.i=X.i)$objective
               }
ll
[1] 55160.06 65839.87 50232.35 74536.11 73489.52 80321.76 61646.76 61899.84 76774.73 74138.7
```

However, I'm not able to apply `foreach()`, since it seems that `nlminb()` does not recognize the input data `X.i`, or at least does not manage it in the same way as when embedded into `for()`:

```
doMC::registerDoMC(cores=2)

ll.foreach<-foreach(i=1:B,.packages = c("stats","plyr"),.combine = c)   %dopar% {
                 X.i<-f_bwhv(X,resampling=T)
                 nlminb(par,F_1,X.i=X.i)$objective
                }

Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'X.i' not found"
```

I do not know where is the problem, but I guess it must be something specifically related with how `foreach()`, and `nlminb()`  interact, because if I  run `foreach()` with a simple function, lets say, measure the number of rows in X.i, I got no problem at all:

```
nrows.foreach<-foreach(i=1:B, .packages = c("stats","plyr"), .combine = c) %dopar% { 
                 X.i<-f_bwhv(X,resampling=T)
                 nrow(X.i)
                 }

nrows.foreach
118 118 116 116 118 117 116 115 108 113
```

I'm not familiar with the `foreach` package, and I failed to find a solution in the package help, therefore I would appreciate a lot your suggestions.

I used here:

R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03); doMC version 1.3.4; foreach version 1.4.3; 
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem by myself, just want to share it in case someone falls into the same issue. After several trials, I realized the problem was on how I defined F_1. Originally, I specified the function as it follows:

```
F_1<-function(par,...){*some calculations involving par and X.i* }
```

using the ,...,  to pass X.i into the function. This worked always for me in other routines. The solution came simply by altering the header of the function in this way:

```
F_1<-function(par,X.i){*some calculations involving par and X.i* }
```

Cheers